# Use a database with mongodb `connect`

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I can connect to mongodb with:

```
const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://user:pass@host/mydb', {
    useNewUrlParser: true
})
```

Then in order to perform queries I have to use a `db` object. I can get it via:

```
const db = await client.db('mydb')
```

It seems redundant, because I have to give the database name twice. Can I avoid the second step? (assuming I can't change the URL given to the connect function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`db()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html#db) without any arguments. In such case the name from your connection string will be used.

> **dbName**    *string*    optional
>   The name of the database we want to use. If not provided, use database name from connection string.

```
const db = await client.db() // mydb is used
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the URL given to the connect function but you can definitely extract the db name by parsing the url and getting the name i.e.

```
const url = require('url')
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')

const mongodbServerUrl = 'mongodb://user:pass@host/mydb'
const mongoPathName = url.parse(mongodbServerUrl).pathname
const dbName = mongoPathName.substring(mongoPathName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)

const client = await MongoClient.connect(mongodbServerUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
})

const db = await client.db(dbName)
```